# windows vista: is there a way to see the startup messages instead of the loading bar

Tags: windows-vista, boot

My Windows Vista installation is hanging on the loading bar and never leaves it.

Is there a way to see what it's actually doing? Such as by getting the text print-out of what it's loading as an alternative to the graphical loading bar start-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

1.) Open MsConfig from the Start Search or from a command prompt (CMD).

2.) Select the System Configuration “Boot” tab and place a check in the box for “No GUI Boot”

3.) Then reboot your PC

http://www.myitforum.com/articles/1/view.asp?id=11819

.